# I've written two different functions with identical behavior. Which is more Pythonic?

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

I'm very new to Python and have recently been practicing writing simple functions. Both of the functions below check if a character string is a palindrome. Is one method more "Pythonic" than the other or is my question moot because there is another better way to do this?

```
def is_palindrome_recursive(word):
    if len(word) == 1:
        return True
    elif len(word) == 2:
        if word[0] == word[1]:
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)
    elif word[0] != word[-1]:
        return False
    else:
        return is_palindrome_recursive(word[1:-1])
```

```
def is_palindrome_while(word):
    while len(word) > 2:
        if word[0] != word[-1]:
            return False
        else:
            word = word[1:-1]
    if len(word) == 1:
        return True
    elif word[0] == word[1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And finally, is this an appropriate question for Stack Overflow or does it belong in a more subjective forum?

Comment: In python this can be done by using this: `phrase = "CABBAC"
print(phrase.find(phrase[::-1]))`. You just have to reverse the whole string and then compare. `phrase[::-1]==phrase`

Comment: Wow, thanks @Pygirl, that is a much better solution.